# Plotly Mapbox images showing blank with blue background (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter, mapbox

I am running the following code to plot points against a city backdrop using Mapbox within Plotly in a Jupyter Notebook, but the plot does not show up, I just get a blue background.

I suspect that I am not using the token correctly?

```
import plotly.express as px

MBToken = 'pk.[mypublickey]'
px.set_mapbox_access_token(MBToken)

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(dfMaster.dropna()
                        , lat="latitude"
                        , lon="longitude"
                        , color="nta"
                        , size="count_of_testers"
                        #, color_continuous_scale=px.colors.cyclical.IceFire
                        #, size_max=15
                        #, zoom=10
                       )
fig.show()

#fig = px.scatter(x='latitude',y='longitude',data_frame=df)
#fig.show()
```

Running that gives me:
[image]

It does not appear to be a Plotly issue, the commented out code creates a scatter plot (although that has the same blue background, but the points show)

Some other posts have pointed to Jupyter offline mode being the possible culprit, but adding this did not resolve

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
pyo.init_notebook_mode()
```

Additionally, tried starting up the Jupyter notebook with a higher data rate limit as suggested, but no luck there either

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a silent data integrity error, as the `size` field was a string and needed to be converted into numeric